# change file description after upload

Tags: mediawiki

I uploaded an image to my wiki and gave it the wrong description (not caption).  Where can I go to change/correct that uploaded file's `description` text?

I'm running Mediawiki 1.35.1, PHP 7.4, Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) on Ubuntu MATE 20.10.

Comment: Try re-uploading the image.

Comment: Reuploading works, but you can also simply just edit the file page.

Comment: Re-uploading did not work.  The obvious choice of `Submit modified file description` did not work either.  If anyone can test this on their wiki I'd like to know if it works - may be some weird config issue on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting as answer just to show the graphics.  The following graphic goes with my first 2 attempts.

[image]

1st - I tried to re-upload, change the description, and `Submit modified file description`.  This did not work.

2nd - I tried to re-upload, change the description, and `Ignore warning and save file anyway`.  This did not work either.

**Finally** - I simply deleted the file and re-uploaded it with new description.  **This worked**.  Be sure to keep the identical file name.

[image]